# can you browse a asp.net website that has a app_offline.htm file in use?

Tags: .net, asp.net, deployment

when using the `app_offline.htm` file to take a site offline while uploading a new version, is there any way to browse the site to make sure everything is ok prior to deleting this file and bringing the app back online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. That's the whole point of `app_offline.htm` - [it takes the asp.net application off-line as well](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx).

> if you place a file with this name in the root of a web application directory, ASP.NET 2.0 will shut-down the application, unload the application domain from the server, and stop processing any new incoming requests for that application.  ASP.NET will also then respond to all requests for dynamic pages in the application by sending back the content of the app_offline.htm file

You will need to find an alternate way to do this (for example: setup another site on IIS for testing this and switch over to it when your testing is complete).